# Python pandas resample method doubles dataframe rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime, dataframe

i've read in a csv file into a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
                     Datetime   Value
    0     2017-01-04 00:00:00   0.00
    1     2017-01-04 00:15:00   2.00
    2     2017-01-04 00:30:00   2.00
    3     2017-01-04 00:45:00   1.00
    4     2017-01-04 01:00:00   3.00
    ...
    15542 2017-09-09 23:45:00   8.00

    [15542 rows x 2 columns]
```

Due to failures in the measurement some datetimes are missing. So I used
`resample("15min").mean().fillna(0)`

As far as good, the missing gaps are filled but somehow the new dataframe is not complete - to be exact - the rows beyond a certain datetime are not included(all data after  August 12th) and to my surprise the rows are more than doubled:

```
                     Datetime   Value
    0     2017-01-04 00:00:00   0.00
    1     2017-01-04 00:15:00   2.00
    2     2017-01-04 00:30:00   2.00
    32543 2017-12-08 23:45:00   0.00

    [32544 rows x 2 columns]
```

My aim is simply to read in a csv, fill the missing datetime gaps and set value to 0.00 where datetime was completed. In this special case this should result in `[15552 x 2 columns]` (Annotation: 10 datetime/values needs to be added).

Here is the code:

```
    import pandas as pd

    def read_csv():
        for filename in path:
        file_list.append(filename)
        print(file_list)
        dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', parse_dates=[1], decimal='.', 
                           names=headers)for filename in path]
        df = pd.concat(dfs)
        df_new = df.set_index('Datetime').resample('15 min').mean().fillna(0).reset_index()

        print(df_new)
```

Thought of a reindexing issues but couldnt solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't 2017-12-08 dec 8th not aug 12th?  But either way, seems like a data problem.  I would double check that your index is all dates and not a mix of strings and dates.  You could also try `asfreq` but I think `resample` is fine and you just have some kind of data issue.

Comment: And if you could reproduce the error with a sample data set (rather than just pasting the output) then it would probably be pretty easy to figure out.  As such, without data, all anyone here can do is guess.

Comment: @JohnE good point. First off I thought the same, that it is dec 8th which would have explained the extra rows. But I checked the values coupled to the datetime and verified that it is august (12th). The `index.dtype` of datetime is`datetime64[ns]` and format is `%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S`. I try your suggestion to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

You want to reindex your data, not just resample.

```
import pandas as pd
df = df.set_index('Datetime').resample('15min').mean()
new_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq="15min")
df = df.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
```

This will add in new values into your index based on the provided date_range.

Comment: Hello Gabriel A. Problem still remains. The datetime gaps are filled correctly but now the values are `NaN`. Still dataframe rows end at `2017-12-08 23:45:00` and amount of rows is excessive high `[32544 rows x 1 columns]`.

Comment: You can fill the NA values with 0. I think I need a more detailed explanation of what you want the data to look like

Comment: Okay let me retry to explain it. I have a csv file which contains 2 columns with "Datetime" and "Value" . Amount of rows is `15541`. Datetime starts on `2017-01-04 00:00:00` and ends at `2017-09-09 23:45:00`. In this date range some datetime gaps exist - to be exact 10. That means if i fill the gaps with resample() the total amount of rows in my dataframe should be `15551` within the mentioned date range in my new dataframe. Actually with my code or your posted solution the date range ends to early at `2017-08-12' 23:45:00` and the amount of rows is `32544`. This inconsistency is the problem.